# MikroORM - validate the current SQL db schema as with hbm2ddl.auto=validate

Tags: node.js, orm, nestjs, mikro-orm

Is it possible in MikroORM to validate the current SQL database schema (Postgres)?

I would like run this validation on application start as Hibernate does with `hbm2ddl.auto=validate`

Answer (score 0):

You can use schema generator programatically, this way you can easily check if the schema is up to date after the init:

```
const orm = await MikroORM.init();
const diff = await orm.schema.getUpdateSchemaSQL();

if (diff) {
  throw new Error('schema is out of sync');
}
```

I will consider adding something similar to v6, at least some syntax sugar in the schema generator.

Comment: It might be a workable solution for me (I need to try it out) but it implies that the TS persistence model and database schema have strict one-to-one correspondence. Which in Hibernate is not the case - columns different from the ones generated by the Hibernate schema generator do pass the startup validation.

Comment: You can enable safe mode that won't drop any columns or tables. https://mikro-orm.io/docs/schema-generator

Comment: I tried the solution but it reports a changes also on the valid parts like in text vs varchar(255).

Comment: `text` is not the same as `varchar(255)` ¯\_(ツ)_/¯